# echoing variable gets "Resource id"

Tags: symfony, twig

Using symfony2 I load some entities and then try to iterate over them in a twig template.

However, instead of the variable content I am getting the following:

```
Resource id #23
```

My twig template looks like this:

```
<ol>
{% for post in posts %}
    <li>
        <div>
            {{ post.content }}
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

My controller code is:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppPostBundle:Post');

$reviews = $repository->findBy(
    array('title' => 'my title'))
;
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @cheesemacfly - ok done

Comment: Does your `$reviews` object contain the data you want to be displayed? How do you call the view, `return $this->render('YourBundle:index.html.twig', 
                array('posts' => $reviews));`?

Comment: Can you please post your "post" entity code? It seems to me that content is not a string or getContent() function in the entity does not return a string either.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is too late for this answer (definitely it is LOL) but I recently had the same issue and the problem is that blob datatypes are treated as a buffer, so you have to read the info using buffer functions.

In your entity `Post` code you may add this method:

```
public function readContent(){
    $content = '';
    while(!feof($this->getContent())){
        $content.= fread($this->getContent(), 1024);
    }
    rewind($this->getContent());
    return $content;
}
```

Then in your views you may call the `readcontent` method instead of `content`:

```
<ol>
{% for post in posts %}
    <li>
        <div>
            {{ post.readcontent }}
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Is better late than never :)

Answer (score 1):

My entity name is : 'Test'

Blob type field is : 'Details'

in '/src/Vendorname/Bundlename/Entity/entityname.php'

```
 **
 * Get details
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDetails()
{
    return $this->details;
}
/**
 * Reading the blob type of content.
 * @return data
 */
public function readDetails(){
  $details = '';
  while(!feof($this->getDetails())){
    $details.= fread($this->getDetails(), 1024);
   }
  rewind($this->getDetails());
  return $details;
}
```

and in  '*.html.twig' file

```
{% for match in matches %} 
    {{match.readdetails}}
{%endfor%}
```